# What's a weapon mount?

Tags: sword-of-the-stars-the-pit

I just found a plasma cannon, and in its description there's a "mount" entry:

[image: plasma cannon with "mount" circled]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Brawler PBA](http://sword-of-the-stars-the-pit.wikia.com/wiki/Brawler_PBA) is an armor suit. You need the Brawler PBA to actually use the plasma cannon.

Comment: As is the case with all heavy weapons.